# How does CosmosDB change feed behave in the presence of multi-master replication?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have CosmosDB set up in multi-master mode replicated to several sites, and am utilizing the change feed API to read updates from the database. Currently I am reading from a single location, but soon I plan to read from multiple for failover redundancy. What isn't clear is how the change feed API is supposed to behave in this scenario. If the timestamp that change feed uses to poll for changes is copied directly from the originating site, I can imagine some timing situations where change feed would not see the changes since the Continuation Token is already in the future. I wouldn't expect any problems if the timestamp is updated on the replicated site. While I can test this myself to verify, I would prefer to know what is explicitly supported by the CosmosDB team.

Comment: When you say "watermark" token, do you mean the checkpoints generated by the Change Feed Processor Library?

Comment: Matias, yes I am referring to the change feed checkpoints returned by the change feed query.

Comment: Could you share a code sample of how are you consuming the Change Feed? To understand which is the watermark you refer to in code (I don't see any watermark attribute or information as part of the Change Feed request)

Comment: Matias I should have used the term "continuation token". I am simply calling CreateDocumentChangeFeedQuery and storing ResponseContinuation per docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient.createdocumentchangefeedquery?view=azure-dotnet.

Comment: Thanks Peter for the clarification. Could you also add to the post, for other's context, the snippet of how you read the Change Feed and if you will be reading from all regions at the same time or if you will expect your CreateDocumentChangeFeedQuery to transparently failover to another region?

Comment: My question isn't about failover, but whether reading the change feed from both locations will work correctly in a multi master setup.

Comment: It should, yes, Change Feed contains all changes coming from all regions.

Answer (score 1):

All changes that happen in all regions are replicated to each region's Change Feed, so you should be able to read the Change Feed from any of the regions and obtain all the changes without issues.